# shorter neater way to find and insert text

Tags: powershell

I can complete this task easily using my own method but I come across this and found it very neat, was wondering how I could modify it to my needs.

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\gerhardl\Documents\My Received Files" -Filter *.txt | `
Foreach-Object{
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName

    #filter and save content to the original file
    $content | Where-Object {$_ -match '[rabbit]'} | Set-Content $_.FullName

}
```

what i would like to do is insert a block of text under [rabbit] although [rabbit] may appear more than once so in that case i would have to randomly select what one to insert my block of text under. the text would be stored in a variable. Sorry if this isn't explained so good, my English isn't the best.

Comment: Do you already have code that does what you describe that you could show us?

Comment: Note that `-match '[rabbit]'` is identical to `-match '[abirt]'`, and that `'r' -match '[rabbit]'`, `'Audrey' -match '[rabbit]'`, and `'Bill' -match '[rabbit]'` will return True.

Comment: I have written my own small line, the thing that's missing is knowing what line number has been randomly chosen, all i get back from this is "true/false". `$c = get-content $_.FullName | foreach { $_ -match "[rabbit]" } | Get-Random`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you actually mean to match a literal string `"[rabbit]"` rather than the regular expression `[rabbit]` you could do something like this:

```
$file = 'C:\path\to\your.txt'

(Get-Content $file) | % {
  $_
  if ($_ -like '*`[rabbit`]*') {
    'text you want to insert'
  }
} | Set-Content $file
```